# Difference between jquery selector by String and domElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Recently I found some strange code in my project. It runs well, however I don't understand why they using this way.

```
$($('#' +targetDiv)[0])
```

Is it a bug or any other reason to use this way instead of using $('#' +targetDiv)?

It seems both selector indicate same dom element.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `$($(selector)[0])` is a jQuery object containing only the first match, whereas `$(selector)` is a jQuery object that can *possible* contain more than just the first match.

In other words, `$(selector)[0]` will retrieve the first DOM element in the jQuery object. Wrapping the the DOM element with `$()` will return a jQuery object. On the other hand, `$(selector)` will retrieve all the matches (which *could* be more than just the first match).

A better way to re-write `$($(selector)[0])` would be `$(selector).eq(0)`.

For example:

```js
$($('.example1')[0]).css('background-color', '#f00');

$('.example2').css('background-color', '#0f0');

$('.example3').eq(0).css('background-color', '#00f');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="example1">$($('.example1')[0])</p>
<p class="example1">$($('.example1')[0])</p>
<p class="example1">$($('.example1')[0])</p>
<hr />
<p class="example2">$('.example2')</p>
<p class="example2">$('.example2')</p>
<p class="example2">$('.example2')</p>
<hr />
<p class="example3">$('.example3').eq(0)</p>
<p class="example3">$('.example3').eq(0)</p>
<p class="example3">$('.example3').eq(0)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), jQuery object takes the following objects in its *overloads*:

> selector
>   element
>   elementArray
>   object
>   selection
>   html

They all produce valid jQuery objects and are useful in different situations. However, in your case, it looks like someone just didn't know how to do this:

```
$('#' +targetDiv).eq(0)
```

It may be a good idea to modify this code in order to not confuse someone else in future. Moreover, that solution may have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks Yeldar, that's the answer I am looking for.